# Problem loading images in JS, how to avoid 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, load

I get some errors in the console "GET ... 404 (Not Found)"
I test the images when the mouse is on it. 
If there is an image I show it, and if there is not I keep the first version.
It's working but I still getting the error in the console when the image doesn't exist.

```
  const handleOver = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const saveTarget = e.target
        if (saveTarget.src) {
            let copie = saveTarget.src
            let img = new Image()
            img.addEventListener('load', () => {
                saveTarget.src = img.src
            })
            img.addEventListener('error', () => { 
                console.log('error')
            })
            img.src = copie.replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '_bw.jpg')
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you tell the browser to fetch something from a URL, and the server responds with an error, the browser informs the user that it didn't work. Have your server respond with a default image if you don't like the error.

Comment: As a alternative option to @Pointy's you could use an ajax request (by using e.g. `fetch`) and check the status code of that request. Might not be the most efficient way, buy you will certainly know for sure.